# Check embedded youtube video view count from my page

Tags: youtube, embedded-video

My question is very similar to [Tracking Youtube player embedded video view count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378503/tracking-youtube-player-embedded-video-view-count) . However, I could not find an answer to it. So I want to know the various ways this can be done.

Basically, I have a youtube video embedded onto my page. I am not the owner of the video. I want to know how many times this video is played from my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the Youtube Javascript player API and look for the play event as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Adding_event_listener)